# Asserting and using fast, LARGE arrays in prolog

Tags: arrays, prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

I'm using functors to get random-access arrays using arg/3 in SWI-Prolog.
What i'm doing is loading values from a sample into a functor I create and asserting the array for future use.

Once loaded, Random access is indeed O(1) as I've verified using time/1. The issue is loading the functor from the assertion takes a lot of time ( time/1 suggests it's linear in the size of the array ).
Is there any way i can speed this up to constant time?

Minimal code for reproduction:

```
:- dynamic
    current_sample/1.

xrange(L,R,X):-
    L < R,
    ( X = L;
    X1 is L+1, xrange(X1,R,X)
    ).


arraybase_from_list__set_arg_from_list([], _, _).
arraybase_from_list__set_arg_from_list([Head|Tail], I, ResArray):-
    I1 is I+1,
    nb_setarg(I1, ResArray, Head),
    arraybase_from_list__set_arg_from_list(Tail, I1, ResArray).

arraybase_from_list(List, ResArray):-
    length(List, L),
    functor(ResArray, custom_array_data, L),
    arraybase_from_list__set_arg_from_list(List, 0, ResArray ).


test_array_create( N ):- % Creates a dummy array of squares of numbers fromo [0,N)
    findall( X2, (xrange( 0,N,X), X2 is X*X), XList ),
    arraybase_from_list( XList, Arr ),
    assert( current_sample(Arr) ).

test_array_get(I,V):- % Unifies V with Ith element of Current sample
    I0 is I+1,
    current_sample(Arr), % Take turns timing this
    arg( I0, Arr, V ).   % And then timing this
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing **linear** overhead when using `current_sample/1` because the arguments of predicates are **copied** from the database when a predicate is called.

There are several ways to get rid of this *linear* overhead, turning it into **𝒪(1)**.

## A good way

A *good* way to do it is to  **carry around** the whole array, either explicitly or implicitly, throghout all predicates that need to access it.

You can use **semicontext notation** to do it implicitly (see [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)), or write your own custom expansion rules. This is similar to **monads** in Haskell.

> **Consider doing this!**

---

## A much worse way

A much worse and only on the surface easier way is to use *global variables* instead of the the global **database** to store the term.

> **Avoid this!**

Some reasons:

- it's **not portable**
- it introduces **global state**, making your predicate hard to read and debug
- it's **not** significantly more efficient than simply using additional arguments to carry the array through (implicitly or explicitly)
- it's **error prone**
- etc.

Comment: Thank you
Unfortunately I'm a bit tight on time so I'm going for the easy solution of using a global variable here. DCG is something I'll have to pick up soon.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to tell me this!